# Relationships not bi-directional

Tags: gremlin, titan

Please explain this...

```
gremlin> g.v(20482816).inE

==>e[dpulc-dpurk-8v85-c70n4][23041280-status->20482816]
==>e[dpuww-dpuyo-8wt1-c70n4][23041536-status->20482816]

gremlin> g.V().has('text').outE()

==>e[dpuww-dpuyo-8wt1-c70n4][23041536-status->20482816]
==>e[dpv4w-dpvk0-8wt1-c70n4][23042304-status->20482816]
==>e[dpv28-dpvcw-8wt1-c70n4][23042048-status->20482816]
==>e[dpuzk-dpv5s-8wt1-c70n4][23041792-status->20482816]
==>e[dpva8-dpvy8-8wt1-c70n4][23042816-status->20482816]
==>e[dpv7k-dpvr4-8wt1-c70n4][23042560-status->20482816]
```

The second query shows that `20482816` is the target of several edges. So why does the first query not return all of those edges?

Here is the query that I used to create the second set of edges...

```
v1 = g.addVertex([text: 'hello']);
v2 = g.V().has('userId', '1234').next();
g.addEdge(v1, v2, 'status');
g.commit();
```

Oddly, this query returns what I'd expect of the very first query...

```
g.V().has('text').out.dedup.in
```

**EDIT:**

Oh... so today it just started working as expected. huh?

Comment: Is this with Cassandra? Could this be a (to be expected) consistency issue? Perhaps a prior transaction was successful on some servers but failed on others?

Comment: Yes I'm using the Cassandra backend. But there's only one server as far as I know.